# Getting certificates from PKCS11 Smartcard without PIN/password on a DNIe

Tags: java, cryptography

I want to find some libraries for Windows since I'm trying to extract the public certificate of a smartcrd (DNIe, spanish national document) without pin for school purposes.
There is my code, but I guess the problem is with the library:

```
String pkcs11Config = "name = SmartCard\nlibrary = C:\\SCMNIGHT\\opensc-pkcs11.dll";
ByteArrayInputStream confStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11Config.getBytes());
Provider prov = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(confStream);
Security.addProvider(prov);
KeyStore cc = null;
String pin = "";
try {
    cc = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11",prov);
    KeyStore.PasswordProtection pp = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(pin.toCharArray());
    cc.load(null ,  pp.getPassword() );
    Enumeration aliases = cc.aliases();
    while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
        Object alias = aliases.nextElement();
        try {
            X509Certificate cert0 = (X509Certificate) cc.getCertificate(alias.toString());
            System.out.println("I am: " + cert0.getSubjectDN().getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            continue;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

since im getting;

```
java.io.IOException: load failed
at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineLoad(P11KeyStore.java:766)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
at com.mycompany.tests.Example.main(Example.java:38)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.login(SunPKCS11.java:1238)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.login(P11KeyStore.java:864)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineLoad(P11KeyStore.java:753)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_PIN_LEN_RANGE
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_Login(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.login(SunPKCS11.java:1222)
    ... 4 more
```

I'm using open sc pkcs reader and Java PKCS11.
Any ideas, suggests or commentaries?

Comment: java.io.IOException: load failed
 at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineLoad(P11KeyStore.java:766)
 at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
 at com.mycompany.tests.Example.main(Example.java:38)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: no password provided, and no callback handler available for retrieving password
 at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.login(SunPKCS11.java:1184)
 at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.login(P11KeyStore.java:864)
 at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineLoad(P11KeyStore.java:751)
 ... 2 more

Comment: afer trying with null value. PasswordProtection prvents it I guess

Comment: `PasswordProtection` prevents nothing. Look at how you're using it. The keystore never even sees it. All you're doing is putting a char array into it and getting it out again.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the PIN just to get out public certificates. In any case `""` is an empty PIN, not an absent PIN. Try it will `null` instead of `pin.toCharArray()` or indeed `pp.getPassword()`. In fact I don't see the point of using `KeyStore.PasswordProtection` at all here.

But evidently you do need the PIN, and there is one, so you need to find out what it is, probably from the user, and provide it to `load()`.